# SQLite Query Performance Time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query which takes too much time (since last 1 hour is still running) to execute:

```
select RL.[LINK_ID] as LINK_ID, RPA.[POSTAL_AREA_ID] as POSTAL_AREA_ID, RRN.[STREET_NAME] as STREET_NAME 
from RDF_LINK as RL, RDF_POSTAL_AREA as RPA, RDF_ROAD_LINK as RRL, RDF_ROAD_NAME as RRN 
where RRL.[ROAD_NAME_ID] = RRN.[ROAD_NAME_ID]
AND RPA.[POSTAL_AREA_ID] IN (RL.[LEFT_POSTAL_AREA_ID], RL.[RIGHT_POSTAL_AREA_ID]) 
AND RL.[LINK_ID] = RRL.[LINK_ID]
```

All the columns which are part of the query are indexed.
The ANALYZE command has already been. performed on database.
The database has approx. 73 millions records in the RDF_ROAD_LINK table and same number of records in other tables.

Is there any other way around to write this query?

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
select RL.[LINK_ID] as LINK_ID, RPA.[POSTAL_AREA_ID] as POSTAL_AREA_ID, RRN.[STREET_NAME] as STREET_NAME 
from RDF_LINK as RL, RDF_POSTAL_AREA as RPA, RDF_ROAD_LINK as RRL, RDF_ROAD_NAME as RRN 
where RRL.[ROAD_NAME_ID] = RRN.[ROAD_NAME_ID]
AND RPA.[POSTAL_AREA_ID] IN (RL.[LEFT_POSTAL_AREA_ID], RL.[RIGHT_POSTAL_AREA_ID]) 
AND RL.[LINK_ID] = RRL.[LINK_ID]
```

Output ::

```
0   0   3   SCAN TABLE RDF_ROAD_NAME AS RRN
0   1   2   SEARCH TABLE RDF_ROAD_LINK AS RRL USING INDEX IND_ROAD_NAME_ID (ROAD_NAME_ID=?)
0   2   0   SEARCH TABLE RDF_LINK AS RL USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_LINK_1 (LINK_ID=?)
0   3   1   SEARCH TABLE RDF_POSTAL_AREA AS RPA USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_POSTAL_AREA_1 (POSTAL_AREA_ID=?)
0   0   0   EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
```

Comment: *Sigh*. EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

Comment: @CL. .. Explain query plan results are added ... it's scanning RDF_ROAD_NAME table .. i don't know why although ROAD_NAME_ID is primary key in that table and also i created indexed on same column.

Answer (score 1):

This query returns all 73 million records, and has to look up the corresponding records from the other tables.
This cannot be fast because there is too much data to be cached (and with this size, it's likely that not even the indexes fit into the cache).

In a join between two tables, the database goes through all rows of the first table, and looks up the corresponding row(s) of the second table.
This means that the first table always ends up with a `SCAN`, because it would not make sense to use an index (going through an index would not be any faster when you need to load all rows anyway).

In this case, using an index for `RDF_ROAD_NAME` would be possible only if there were an additional filter on an indexed column (`WHERE STREET_NAME = 'My Street'`), or if the result must be sorted by an indexed column (`ORDER BY ROAD_NAME_ID`).

If the tables have many columns that are not used in this query, you might be able to speed it up a little bit by using [covering indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) (if all data you need is already in the index, the database does not need to look up the corresponding table row):

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON RDF_ROAD_LINK(ROAD_NAME_ID, LINK_ID);
CREATE INDEX ... ON RDF_LINK(LINK_ID, LEFT_POSTAL_AREA_ID, RIGHT_POSTAL_AREA_ID);
```